# LDAP - Find user by name only

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory, ldap

I am not too familiar with LDAP, however I am working on authentication in a Node.js app, and the user credentials for the web app is going to be gotten from the organization's Windows domain.

I have LDAP lookups working (using the `Passport.js` Node module), however to make it work, I have to put the user's full-fledged DN into Node. For example, let's say:

1. My FQDN is `mydomain.private.net`.
2. My users are stored in an organizational unit, let's say `staff`.

Now, if I want to lookup user `joe`, I have to put this string into Node:

```
var username = 'CN=joe,OU=staff,DC=mydomain,DC=private,DC=net';
```

#### do i really have to keep track of all that?

What if my users are in two different organizational units? The client-side browser doesn't know that! It just knows:

```
username = 'joe';
password = 'xxxxx';
```

What if you try to log on as administrator? Administrators are always in a totally different OU by default.

Is there a way to reference an LDAP object by just the name and nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general LDAP problem. You need to get a unique identifier from the user, and then look for it.

Typically this is what the `uid` attribute is used for.  Active Directory may or may not have that populated, and generally relies on sAMAccountName which must be unique within the domain.

So you need a two step process.

1) Query for uid=joe or samAccountName=joe
2) Use the results to test a bind or password compare.

You would then use the `DC=mydomain,DC=private,DC=net` value as the root to search from.

Comment: Thanks - I had managed to figure this out finally a little while ago, but your answer did point to the correct solution, which I detailed below. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### (answer to my own question)

geoffc's answer was correct, and this is the working solution adapted to my Node.js app using the `activedirectory` npm module:

```
  // First search for the user itself in the domain.
  // If successfully found, the findUser function
  // will return the full DN string, which is
  // subsequently used to properly query and authenticate
  // the user.
  var AD = self.ADs[domain];
  AD.findUser(username, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      cb(false, 'AD error on findUser', err);
      return;
    }
    if (!user) {
      cb(false, 'User does not exist', void 0);
    } else {
      username = user.dn;
      AD.authenticate(username, password, function(err, authenticated) {
        if (authenticated == false) {
          cb(false, err, void 0);
          return;
        } else {
          cb(true, 'Authenticated', void 0);
        }
      });  
    }
  });
```